# Lie Derivative equals the commutator of two vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, vector-fields

The Lie derivative $L_X$ of a vector field w.r.t. to another is defined as 
$$
L_X(Y)= \lim_{ε\to 0} [(σ_{-ε})_*(Y|_{σ_ε(x)}-Y|_x]
$$
Where $σ$ denotes flow of the vector field X and $_*$ denotes pushforward. How do we prove using this definition that the Lie derivative will equal $[X,Y]$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: you can find a proof of this statement on Nakahara "Geometry topology and physics" section 5.3.2